# how to use accumulate for multiple operation and collection

Tags: java, drools

I am using below rule to get the two collection list.

```
rule "base"
    when
        $priceLineItem : PriceLineItem( $grade : grade , $style : style  ,$prefix : prefix , basePrice == null  )
    then
end

rule "check-multiple instance-on-cover-type" extends "base"
    when
        accumulate (
                    $basePriceUpchargeConfig : BasePriceUpchargeConfig( 
                                                prefix contains $prefix,
                                                style contains $style,
                                                $baseCoverType : baseCoverType 
                                            )
                     and
                     $c : CoverUpChargeConfig( 
                                                baseCoverType contains $baseCoverType.get(0),
                                                gradeOrder contains $grade,
                                                prefix  contains $prefix,
                                                style  contains $style
                                           );
                     $collectList : collectList($c) )
            accumulate (
                    $basePriceUpchargeConfig : BasePriceUpchargeConfig( 
                                                prefix contains $prefix,
                                                style contains $style,
                                                $baseCoverType : baseCoverType 
                                            )
                     and
                     $c : CoverUpChargeConfig( 
                                                baseCoverType contains $baseCoverType.get(0),
                                                gradeOrder contains $grade,
                                                prefix  contains $prefix,
                                                style  contains $style
                                           );
                     $collectList1 : collectList($basePriceUpchargeConfig) )

    then
        System.out.println($collectList);
        System.out.println($collectList1);
end
```

I want the list of CoverUpChargeConfig and also BasePriceUpchargeConfig object in then consequence.

1. For each BasePriceUpchargeConfig; there would be multiple or exactly one CoverUpChargeConfig  object. if there is exactly one to one between both object; I want to use it in THEN part of the rule.
2. If there is one to multiple match between BasePriceUpchargeConfig --> CoverUpChargeConfig ; I want to know the number of CoverUpChargeConfig object.

I am able to get it in the above way but I am using two accumulate.

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect two lists in the same accumulate CE - I didn't see any difference in the two accumulates for pairing BasePriceUpchargeConfig and CoverUpChargeConfig.

```
rule "check-multiple instance-on-cover-type" extends "base"
when
accumulate ( $b: BasePriceUpchargeConfig( 
             prefix contains $prefix,
             style contains $style,
             $baseCoverType : baseCoverType  )
             and
             $c : CoverUpChargeConfig( 
             baseCoverType contains $baseCoverType.get(0),
             gradeOrder contains $grade,
             prefix  contains $prefix,
             style  contains $style );
            $collectList1 : collectList($b)
            $collectList : collectList($c) )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Laune....I missed very basic while I was doing.I was almost there. Thanks a lot again. It is working.

Comment: But when I am using the above list collectList1 and collectList: in then part, I am getting ClassCastException. I am not able to use the above list value